# How to Display Onclick Popup Only Once

Tags: javascript, onclick, popup

i have a question about onclick popup. How to make it show only once per unique, because the popup link always opened after i click everywhere on my website.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function load() {window.open('http://...','_blank');}
</script>
```

So, how to make it show only once?

Comment: How are you attaching this handler with `onclick`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try storing the state of your popup in a var :

```
var popupShown = false;

function load() {
    if(!popupShown) window.open('http://...','_blank');
    popupShown=true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now my onclick popup only display once if i click on slected page.

Answer (score 1):

Based on information provided I assume that you are trying to attach the `load` handler to one of your target element on `click` event and after first click the event handler should not fire.

Hence I can suggest you to use the `once` option of the `addEventListener()` method:

```
element.addEventListener('click', load.bind(this), false, false);
```

Get more info here at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: In the jquery world, use 'one' method which accepts event name and callback. See here: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this

Store your window state in one variable and re use it when you want to open other URL

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var popupWin = null;
   function load() {
       popupWin =   window.open('http://...','_blank');
   }

  function openOtherURL(){      
     popupWin.location.href = url;

  }

</script>
```